# Print percentage of completion in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, progress-bar

I want to print the percentage of completion of model building in Tensorflow. Or something like a progress bar to show the progress of model building in real time. Any help friends?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution. A useful package that I like to use is tqdm. Allows you to see a progress bar which in my opinion is very useful. https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm